# Image re-sizing while uploading via drupal 7 dashboard

Tags: media

I am looking for an option to re-size the images while uploading from a content type.

I can set the max upload size to 8 mb and while user uploads the images it should be resized to a lesser size automatically.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps.

1) Add new image style from Configuration->image style

2) Go to your content type and Edit the image field

3) Select your newly created image style from the "preview image style" dropdown list and then save settings.

Now the images will be resized according to your created style.

Answer (score 1):

You should check these modules:

1. [Image Resize Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_resize_filter) :

   - Automatically resizes both local and (optionally) remote images.
   - Optionally create a link to full size images from the resized inline
     versions.
   - Prevents inline "hot linking" of images from other sites by
     storing them locally.
   - Adds height and width attributes to inline
     images when your users are too lazy to add them.
2. [Image API optimize](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageapi_optimize/) :

> Despite the name, this module does not depend on ImageAPI. It depends
>   only on the core image.module. Please read the [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/773342) page for
>   more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the maximum size for the image field. That means you could have individual settings for every content type and for every image field you use. Just check the settings on `structure > content types > my content type > fields > image field`. The images will then be resized to a maximum size according to your settings.